# How to use label values in Prometheus queries?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I want to create a Grafana dashboard showing the free memory grouped by the Linux buddy block sizes. The node_exporter collects the buddyinfo from the kernel:

```
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="0",zone="Normal"}  2474
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="1",zone="Normal"}  2934
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="2",zone="Normal"}  2743
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="3",zone="Normal"}  1191
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="4",zone="Normal"}  811
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="5",zone="Normal"}  289
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="6",zone="Normal"}  127
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="7",zone="Normal"}  67
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="8",zone="Normal"}  28
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="9",zone="Normal"}  39
node_buddyinfo_blocks{node="0",size="10",zone="Normal"} 43474
```

Instead of displaying the number of free buddy block, the block counts needs to be converted into the size in bytes by multiplying the block count (the metric value) with the size of the block (derived from the size label):

```
blocks * 2 ^ size * PAGESIZE
```

For that calculation I like to use the value of the label `size` and write something like:

```
sum by (size) (node_buddyinfo_blocks) * (2 ^ size)
```

Is there a way to implement that query in prometheus?

As workaround, ten queries could be hard-coded for each buddy size.